# "and that skill is always a class skill for you" - does "always" have any meaning in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, character-advancement

Many traits and (some feats, if my memory is right) have this rule written in them. For example:

> [Trap Finder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/campaign-traits/mummy-s-mask/trap-finder/)
>
> Benefit(s): You gain a +1 trait bonus on Disable Device checks, **and that skill is always a class skill for you**. In addition, you can use Disable Device to disarm magic traps, like a rogue.

Emphasis mine.

I'm unsure about the "always" word. Back in the days of 3.5, if you were spending points on cross-class skills, you got ½ of a rank per skill point spent. Thus, abilities that made a skill an always class skill was very usable for characters wanting to multiclass or take PrC.

In Pathfinder, only effect of skill being a class skill is +3 bonus. Thus, there is no sense to say that skill is **always** a class skill, right? It either is or is not?

Is there any meaning, rules-wise, to this **always** word in such rules? Am I forgetting something that makes it meaningful? Or is it but a reminiscent of D&D 3.5 era?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That word is only there because of certain rules were changed between 3.5 and Pathfinder, such as how **class skills** work and how multiclassing works, and they needed to clarify that the skill is a class skill regardless of your class(es). It has no actual effect, if a skill is a class skill, it is a class skill regardless of your classes and other mechanics, and there are no mechanics that make it *not* be a class skill for you.

However, there are archetypes that change your class skills for *that* class, and saying that this *always* count as a class skill should bypass a possible removal from an archetype. There are many examples of this, but to name one, the [Urban Bloodrager](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/archetypes/paizo-bloodrager-archetypes/urban-bloodrager-bloodrager-archetype/) *removes* some skills from their list of *class skills*:

> Class Skills: An urban bloodrager adds Diplomacy (Cha), Knowledge (local) (Int), Linguistics (Int), and Profession (Wis) as class skills, and **removes Handle Animal (Cha), Knowledge (nature) (Int), and Survival (Wis)**.